# Как распаковать ZIP Архив при помощи Python скрипта?

Tags: python, zip

Как распаковать ZIP Архив при помощи Python скрипта?

Answer (score 2):

```
import zipfile
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(file='path-to-file.zip')
    zfile.extractall('outpath');
```

Но deflate64, вроде как, не поддерживается.

Answer (score 0):

распаковывать архив не на диск, а в переменную:

```
import io, pickle, zipfile

def extract_zip_to_var(zip_file_name: str) -> [bytes]:
    """распаковать сожержимое архива zip_file_name в переменную data"""
    zip_f = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name)
    data = list(map(zip_f.read, zip_f.namelist()))
    return data

def write_data_to_disk_from_var(data, file_name: str, zip_file: str, ) -> None:
    """упаковать переменную data, внутрь файла-архива zip_file, в файл file_name"""
    zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=False) as zf:
        zf.writestr(file_name, (data.getvalue() if isinstance(data, io.BytesIO) else data))
    with open(zip_file, 'wb') as zfa:
        zfa.write(zip_buffer.getvalue())
    return

def dump_to_var(data) -> 'io.BytesIO':
    """дапм объекта в переменную, которую потом можно упаковать в zip"""
    bio = io.BytesIO()
    pickle.dump(data, bio)
    return bio


if __name__ == '__main__':
    VAR = {1: [2, (3,), ], 4: {('qwertyuiop'), }, }  # объект для запаковки
    bio = dump_to_var(VAR)  # <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000215DB5CB830>
    # архивирование VAR
    write_data_to_disk_from_var(bio, 'var.txt', 'var.zip')  # c:\\...\\var.zip[\\var.txt]
    # распаковка VAR
    b_data = extract_zip_to_var('var.zip')  # [b'\x80\x03}q\x00(K\x01]q...', ]
    unziped_VAR = pickle.loads(b_data[0])  # {1: [2, (3,)], 4: {'qwertyuiop'}}
```